# Doctrine - QueryBuilder With leftJoin, regroup fields results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am requesting my database with createQueryBuilder likeso,

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('w as word, uwl.id as wordListId, uwl.status')
    ->from(Word::class, 'w')
        ->leftJoin(UserWordList::class, 'uwl', Join::WITH, 'w.id = uwl.word')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

I am having this result

```
{
    "@context": "\/contexts\/Word",
    "@id": "\/study",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "word": {
                "@id": "\/words\/301217f7-3c84-4287-9f34-c80faf8f708e",
                "@type": "Word",
                "id": "301217f7-3c84-4287-9f34-c80faf8f708e",
                "value": "wear"
            },
            "wordListId": "6478c0ab-0129-4eb9-9ce9-a33cdb57b5b5",
            "status": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

is it possible to gather the leftJoin fields inside my "word" in the result to get something like

```
{
    "word": {
        "@id": "\/words\/301217f7-3c84-4287-9f34-c80faf8f708e",
        "@type": "Word",
        "id": "301217f7-3c84-4287-9f34-c80faf8f708e",
        "value": "wear",
        "wordListId": "6478c0ab-0129-4eb9-9ce9-a33cdb57b5b5",
        "status": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps the other way around, instead of `w` you could have `w.id, w.value, ...`, because word is an entity and it's harder to get something that doesn't belong to the entity inside of it than something that's inside of an entity outside of it. ^^^

Comment: This is something I have tried , but iam using the paginator which results in this error  : The Paginator does not support Queries which only yield ScalarResults

Comment: side question ... is this the standard dbal orm or odm? anyway, the problem still remains, you apparently have some form of mapping onto the Word class, which doesn't contain wordlistid nor status. if you have your relations mapped properly, you might be able to get a `wordlist` key in your `word` containing  the wordlist properties you want ... ultimately, your objective probably isn't really to have a `Word` object that also contains the `wordListId` as a property, but rather you want a *serialization* of a Word object that also contains the wordListId, which is a different problem!

Comment: @Jakumi , iam using api platform bundle , iam using the standard orm i presume